# jquery event fired multiple times

Tags: jquery

In the following code, why is the after event being fired three times? " Text marked!" gets appended three times after the input box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").select(function(){
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").trigger("select");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>

<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are clicking the button 3 times?  I copped the code directly into jsfiddle and it works fine.

Comment: @mmaceachran Not in Chrome, it doesnt: https://jsfiddle.net/rmns4pyq/1/

Comment: FWIW, this appears to be a bug in Chrome. Tried in Firefox and it runs fine.

Comment: I was on FF.  That's weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm this was happening for me in Chrome. I’m really not sure why, but you can fix it by adding `event.preventDefault()`.

```
$("input").select(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("input").after(" Text marked!");
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yedoxov/edit?html,js,output